# Seleccionar campos con id unico y otras condiciones

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo una tabla con varios campos y mi objetivo es traer solo los `id` que aparecen una sola vez y cuyos campos `3` y `4` no sean nulos (alguno de ellos)

La consulta que realice es la siguiente

```
SELECT id
FROM tabla
WHERE campo3 IS NOT NULL
    OR campo 4 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) = 1
```

Pero me trae una lista de `id` donde pruebo y aparecen más de una vez.

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos y versión estás usando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que primero estás filtrando los valores de `campo3` y `campo4` para que no sean nulos, y luego estás viendo los `id`'s que no se repiten.

Lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tabla t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id 
            FROM tabla 
            GROUP BY id 
            HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1 ) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.campo3 IS NOT NULL 
OR t1.campo4 IS NOT NULL;
```

U otra forma:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tabla 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1 
AND (MIN(campo3) IS NOT NULL OR MIN(campo4) IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Lo que hice fue dividir la consulta.

La idea es que primero mire cuales cumplen con la condición de que alguno de esos campos sea nulo, y luego sobre esos se fija si aparecen una sola vez en la tabla.

```
SELECT id
FROM tabla
WHERE (
        campo3 IS NOT NULL
        OR campo 4 IS NOT NULL
        )
    AND id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM tabla
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING count(id) = 1
        )
```

De esta forma solo me trae los registros cuyos campos 3 o 4 no son nulos y que a su vez tienen un `id` que aparece solo una vez en la tabla.

Espero que sirva si alguno tiene una duda parecida.

Comment: ¿No te sirvió la solución de @Lamak? Por otra parte, para fines de futura utilidad, edita la pregunta poniendo la etiqueta del motor de BD que estás usando: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: Si, me sirvio, pero cuando el la publico yo estaba escribiendo la mia por lo cual no la habia visto. Lo hicimos en paralelo. 
Como dice que si pudiste resolverlo respondas a tu pregunta, lo hice. Ademas es otra forma de resolverlo. Si molesta borro mi respuesta.

Comment: No he dicho que moleste ni que tengas que borrarla. Debes evaluar cuál es la solución más óptima y marcar esa respuesta. Hice la pregunta por si se te había escapado valorar el esfuerzo de otros por responder.

Comment: No se me habia escapado, de hecho marque su respuesta como valida apenas la probé y ví que también funcionaba.
Saludos!

Comment: Perfecto. Cuando vi la pregunta  y la respuesta no había solución marcada. Saludos y me alegra que tu problema haya sido resuelto. Vi que también pusiste la etiqueta [tag:sql-server]. Saludos.

Comment: Saludos y gracias por la sugerencia!! :)